# Pesquisar registro por data em mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Boa noite,

Tenho registros na minha tabela sobre fases da lua

```
4089    Lua nova            1983-05-12  19:26:41
4090    Primeiro Trimestre  1983-05-19  14:18:16
4091    Lua cheia           1983-05-26  18:48:29
4092    Quarto Minguante    1983-06-03  21:09:09
4093    Lua nova            1983-06-11  04:38:46
4094    Primeiro Trimestre  1983-06-17  19:47:10
4095    Lua cheia           1983-06-25  08:32:58
4096    Quarto Minguante    1983-07-03  12:14:10
4097    Lua nova            1983-07-10  12:19:30
```

E eu gostaria de pesquisar em que fase da lua estava quando o usuário nasceu, vamos supor que ele nasceu em 25-05-1983 de acordo com os registros abaixo ele nasceu em um Primeiro Trimestre na data 19-05-1983.

Eu tenho a seguinte query

```
Set FL = Conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_lua WHERE data BETWEEN '1983-05-25' AND (SELECT MAX(data) FROM tbl_lua) LIMIT 1")
```

Porém desta forma pega o registro aproximado... aparecendo assim o registro da lua cheia em 26-05-1983

como eu faço para conseguir pegar o registro correto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não seria mais simples assim?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_lua WHERE nascimento >= data ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Teste no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cd31/1)** a versão que retorna luas e trimestres.

Independente da solução adotada, só não se esqueça de incluir a hora na pesquisa para ter a certeza de que a "virada" da lua seja considerada e a pesquisa retorne o dado correto.

Se precisar pegar só o trimestre ou só a lua, basta criar uma diferenciação como esta:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_lua
WHERE
   texto LIKE '%trimestre%' AND
   nascimento >= data
ORDER BY data DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Teste no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ad19a/1)** a versão que só retorna trimestres.

Ou o inverso:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_lua
WHERE
   texto NOT LIKE '%trimestre%' AND
   nascimento >= data
ORDER BY data DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Teste no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/715883/1)** a versão que só retorna luas.

Comment: era exatamente essa ultima opção, muito obrigado pela ajuda.